# Sorting values from a Ruby hash, ignoring case

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

This is how I'm handling values in a Ruby hash to get an alpha-numeric lower-case sorted output (extreme example):

```
myhash = {
  "x" => "zebra",
  "one" => "1",
  "alpeh" => "alpha",
  "lower" => "january",
  "1" => "January",
  "2" => "February",
  "answer" => "42"
}
m = myhash.values
puts m.map{|i| i.downcase}.sort
```

Output:

```
1
42
alpha
february
january
january
zebra
```

This works fine and I don't have a problem with it, but want to know if there's there a simpler/more efficient way I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to modify the values (outputting lowercase strings), I don't think you can do anything better.

If outputting the original values is OK as long as they are well sorted, you could use this :

```
 myhash.values.sort_by{|h|h.downcase}
```

Edit : Thanks to Casper, here's a more compact version :

```
myhash.values.sort_by(&:downcase)
```

Edit : Thanks to Mischa, if you want to keep the output you provided :

```
myhash.values.map(&:downcase).sort
```

Comment: You can make it even more compact with `sort_by(&:downcase)`.

Comment: Similarly the original can be shortened: `myhash.values.map(&:downcase).sort`

Comment: Ah, chose your answer for the refinements (and because it works and is more compact), but the final two versions throw: TypeError: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)

Answer (score 3):

More efficient way than using hash.values (since it creates a temperary array and may be time/space consuming if the hash is large)

```
myhash.sort_by{|_,v| v.downcase}
```

Comment: @daververitt but if you use hash.values, you will split the hash, and create a possibly lengthy array.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more efficient...

m.sort {|a, b| a.casecmp(b)}

=> ["1", "42", "alpha", "February", "January", "january", "zebra"]

Just use a test function that ignores the case on the inputs.  It depends on whether you want you output array to have duplicate values (e.g. january/january vs January/january).

Comment: thanks - it almost does the job but still requires the intermediate `m` array, and casecmp obviously doesn't downcase the values.